# Net Use command fails when running a batch file as an Administrator

Tags: windows, batch-file, administrator, mapped-drive, net-use

I am trying to map a drive with an elevated batch file but any attempt to use the **Net Use** command fails. The error is always: "The system cannot find the drive specified."

I am using the following code: Net Use w: "\Server\Folder"

It works fine with an elevated command prompt or with a non-elevated batch file.

I also tried simply: Net Use
Yet with an elevated batch file even that fails with the same error message.

Comment: Does the elevated account have domain access?

Comment: Ignore that last comment. Obviously the account has access otherwise it wouldn't work from the cmd prompt...

Comment: Have you tried a batch file that contains nothing but the "net use" command?

Comment: Yes, and the result is the same message: "The system cannot find the drive specified."

Answer (score 0):

```
net use DrvLetter: \\server\sharename[\foldername]
```

so

```
net use m: \\serenity\C$
```

Note UNC paths start `\\`

or for any computer this will work to the admin share called C$. `$` means it's a hidden share. Every drive has one (ie D$, E$, ..., Z$) + there is Admin$ (C:\windows), IPC$, and Printer$ (your printer driver folder).

```
net use m: \\%computername%\C$
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. However, using hidden shares doesn't seem to have solved the problem. I am still getting the same message: "The system cannot find the drive specified."